# Won't login at all

Tags: php, session, authentication

So here's what i'm trying to do, I made a login and register in PHP and now my main aim is to make the login work, The difficulty i'm having here is that when I login it doesn't say, "Welcome 'usernamehere' !" Here's my code:

chk.php:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
session_start();

$chk = $_SESSION['login_user'];

$sqlses = mysql_query("select username from users where username='$chk'" );

$row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlses);

$user = $_row['username'];


?>
```

As you can see, I use $user to refer to the user that is logged in.

Here is myprofile.php:

```
<?php

include 'chk.php';

?>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <title>RiDDoW Grabber</title>
 </head>
  <body>
   <center>
      <?php echo "<h1>Welcome" . $user . "!</h1>" ?>
```

Now i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong but here is the login.php too:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
     $username = addslashes($_POST['username']);
     $password = addslashes($_POST['password']);

     $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
     $res = mysql_query($sql);
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
     $act = $_row['active'];
     $count = mysql_num_rows($res);

     if($count == 1) {
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
        echo "Success! Redirecting.... ";
        header("refresh:5;url=myprofile.php");
    } else {
      echo 'Error 1822: Login or Password is not valid. ';
    }
}
?>
```

There aren't any errors or anything it just says "Welcome !" I don't know why or what's going on, But how do I fix this?

Comment: Why are you fetching the username from the database if you already got it in your session: `mysql_query("select username from users where username='$chk'" );`?

Comment: you `echo` something and then call `header`? that should not we working at all.

Comment: @TobiasKun I used this login on many of my websites, I'm not sure why it's not working but I don't think it's that.

Comment: btw: one time you call addslahes before sending the username to the database, the other time not.

Comment: @DaveStallberg: It is no error in my opinion but a useless query you run there...

Comment: So what do I do? It just says Welcome ! and that's it. it doesn't say the user at all, that's my problem. This worked on my previous websites but i don't know why it's not working now

Comment: @DaveStallberg: You should definitely use mysqli_* functions and escape your values before inserting them into you queries. All your websites you are using this code on are **vulnerable**

Comment: @TobiasKun I know, i'm doing it for testing purposes. not for public.